# How to add form fields in flask on button press?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to make a form, where one of the fields is a FormField. I need to be able to add fields on button press. I was thinking maybe it would be possible to simply increase the number of min_entries, but haven't been able to find a way to do so yet.

the form:

```
class addProduct(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Toode")
    price = FloatField('Hind')
    quantity = IntegerField('Inimeste arv', default=0)


class AddOrder(FlaskForm):
    #this is the main form itself, just has fields for the sales header, but what is important to me is this field
    products = FieldList(FormField(addProduct), min_entries=minEntries)
```

And my main question is if it is at all possible to maybe somehow increase the minEntreis variable on button press to be able to add more products per order?

Comment: This is too broad. Please show your code so far as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: Added some code, hope its more understandable

Comment: A bit, thanks, but still missing your button, request initator JS and Flask route handler that manipulates these models.

Comment: To be totally honest I have only failed trying to do it. I have pretty much 0 idea how to go from here after trying everything i thought would work. @ggorlen

Comment: Well since there's not enough code here to show any specific problem at all, there's no way for anyone to help, either, as far as I can see, short of randomly giving you a route, JS and button-pressing behavior that you'd have to adapt to your project somehow but would likely be totally unrelated. 99% of the time these wild guesses don't help you much. "Is it possible?" questions are usually answered in an unhelpful "yes" comment. I'd re-read the [mcve] article which gives guidance on how to ask an answerable question with code.